Can't install packeges in the virtual environment
I am trying to install packges in virtual environment but it is installed in the main python lib folder not in the virtual environment?
When create a virtual environment in windows using this command
python -m venv venv

It creates the virtual environment and then I activate the virtual environment using
venv\Scripts\activate

and then I try to install any packages like
pip install Django

it installes and gets me that the Requirement already satisfied but when try to see the packeges in the venv\lib\site-packages it doesn't show up?

Check out Will libraries installed to my "base" system Python be available in a virtualenv?

Are you on linux or windows?

I am using windows

So, you don't actually have a problem at all.  Your virtual environment package space will only contain those packages that are not already installed in the base system.  If Django is present globally, then you don't NEED another copy in your virtual environment.
